# combine two IIncludedQueryable on same DbSet in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm looking to add an *IIncludedQueryable* object to an existing *IIncludedQueryable* object.

Some of my objects inherit *IClientAccess* and I want to include the related entity's without having to change *IQueryable* code for each entity.

**My code**:

```
public static IQueryable<IStore> StoreLite(IQueryable<IStore> dbSet)
{
    var result = dbSet
        .Include(str => str.VATs)
            .ThenInclude(vat => vat.VAT)
                .ThenInclude(vat => vat.Culture)
                    .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                        .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
        .Include(str => str.Options)
            .ThenInclude(opt => opt.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Option)
        .Include(str => str.Cultures)
            .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
                    .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                        .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
        .Include(str => str.Pages)
            .ThenInclude(page => page.Sections)
                .ThenInclude(section => section.Elements);

    return result;
}

public static IQueryable<IClientAccess> ClientAccess(IQueryable<IClientAccess> dbSet)
{
    var result = dbSet
        .Include(clnt => clnt.ClientAccess)
            .ThenInclude(acc => acc.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Client);

    return result;
}
```

So what I'm thinking in **StoreLite**:

```
var result = dbSet...(existing);

result += ClientAccess(dbSet); //I know this don't work
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to pass the *IQueryable* from *ClientAccess* to the *StoreLite* method in *ShopExpressions*

**GenericExpressions.cs**:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ClientAccess<T>(IQueryable<T> dbSet) where T : class, IBaseData, IClientAccess
{
    var result = dbSet
        .Include(clnt => clnt.ClientAccess)
            .ThenInclude(acc => acc.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Client);

    return result;
}
```

**ShopExpressions.cs**:

```
public static IQueryable<IStore> StoreLite(IQueryable<IStore> dbSet)
{
    var result = dbSet
        .Include(str => str.VATs)
            .ThenInclude(vat => vat.VAT)
                .ThenInclude(vat => vat.Culture)
                    .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                        .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
        .Include(str => str.Options)
            .ThenInclude(opt => opt.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Option)
        .Include(str => str.Cultures)
            .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
                    .ThenInclude(cult => cult.Items)
                        .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Culture)
        .Include(str => str.Pages)
            .ThenInclude(page => page.Sections)
                .ThenInclude(section => section.Elements);

    return result;
}
```

**In use**:

```
public async Task<IStore> GetStoreLite(int id)
{
    IStore result = await ShopExpressions.StoreLite(GenericExpressions.ClientAccess(this.Worker.GetRepo<Store>().DbSet))
        .SingleAsync(str => str.Id.Equals(id));

    this.Worker.ValidateClientAccess(result);

    return result;
}
```